# Sobrepor imagem CSS

Tags: html, css

Tenho 2 imagens, uma é um circulo e a outra é uma imagem com número 360, preciso colocar essa imagem com número 360 dentro da imagem que é um circulo, qual a forma mais correta de se fazer isso? da forma que está to achando que está feio e tem que ficar tudo alinhado com o texto da esquerda

```css
.banner {
  background:orange ;
}

.wrap_description {
  display: flex;
}

.flex_box_description {
  width: 50.0%;
  margin: 10%;
}

.flex_box_text {
  color: #d9dadb;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="wrap_description">
    <div class="flex_box_description">
      <div class="flex_box_text">
        Você está procurando alguma coisa para fazer em Curitiba? Quer você viva na área, tenha se mudado há pouco tempo ou esteja só de passagem, temos várias dicas e eventos imperdíveis. Você pode procurar por local, popularidade, eventos selecionados, eventos
        gratuitos... a escolha é sua. Pronto?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex_box_description">
      <img style="position:absolute; margin-left:1px; top:0px; z-index: 1;" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_lveQq-e41T0/TChewY5E2xI/AAAAAAAAALM/LXlQxG3KwjI/s400/circulo.gif" alt="360" />
      <img style="position:absolute; right:10px; top:70px; z-index: 2;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBw8OEhUQEQ8TEhUQFxUXFRcWFhgPEhogFhYWFhgYFRUYHighGB4lGxYVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLi0BCgoKDg0OGxAQGy0mHyYtLS4yLS0rMC0rLSstLS0rLS0tLTUtLS0tLS8tLS0tKy0tLS0uLS0tLS0tLSstLS0tLf/AABEIAJYAlgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAEAAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABgcBBAUIAwL/xAA9EAABAwIDBQUFBgQHAQAAAAABAAIDBBEFEiEGBzFBURMiYXGBMmKRobEUI1JygpJCssHRFyVDU2ODohX/xAAZAQEAAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMEBQH/xAArEQACAgEEAQIFBAMAAAAAAAAAAQIDEQQSITFBE1EFIjJxkbHB4fBhgaH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/ALxREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAYRfCpqGRNL5HtY0cS4hoHmToohim83DoCWsc+cj/bb3f3OsD6XXqi5dIsrpnY8RTZNkVbQb3aUmzqaZo6jK75XCnmF4jFVxMnhdmZILtOo9CORB0IXsoSj2j22iyr61g3kRFEqMItLE8RhpY3TTSBjGC5JOnkOpPIDUqA4LtdiOL1ZZRtZDSx2zvkZnfa+nO2Z3JvIalSUG1knGuUk5ePcsxFgBZUSARFi6Ayi+QmaSWhwJHEXBI8wvpdAEUW222vZhbY2thdUTVBIiiboTa1ybAm2oGgJN18dj9tWYg91PNA+kqYxmMMlwXD8TLgE+ItfzClseMktjxkmCIiiRC1cRqexikkDS8xsc4NHtHK0mw8TZbSwUPUec8XxWtxWbv55HEkMhYCWt8Gs8OZOvVSDDd1tdK3NK+OC/I3kd6hug+KuCDDII5HzMhY2SW2d4aA51upW4Qr3e8YisHTn8Ukko1RUUjzhtRs3PhsgjmykPBLHtvldbjx1BGlx4hWZuXdJ9jkDvYEzsn7Wl1vC/zuo1vhxdk1RHA0g/ZmuLyNe8+1x6Bo+KsLd5hhpaCFjtHOBe4c7yHMB6AgKdkm61nsu1d0paSLn23/AFkmXyqJ2xtL3kNawEuJ0AAFySvqVVO97agW/wDnxO1NjORyHFsfmdCfCw5rPCDk8HKopds1FER2x2knxipDIw4x5gynj4XJNg5w/E75DTqro2PwBmHUrIBYuHekd+J5Hed5ch4AKt9zuz/ayurXjuwXZFfhnI7x/S0283eCuRW3SS+VdI1a2ai1VDpfqZRF+HuAFybAeg9VQYD41tXHAx0sjwxjBdznGwAHMqktr95lVVOdHSOdTwi4Dh3Zn+8XcWDoBr1K0t4O2MmJSljHWponHI0aB5H+o/r4DkPFauz2wuIYg3tIowyMjR8pLA78osSR42stUK1FbpHRqojWt9hHIqiRj+0ZI9r+OdrnNf55r3Vq7vN5L5HtpK5wJfZsc2jbngGy8rnk7roeqiuK7tcUpml3ZNmA49k7M79hAJ9LqHuHoR6HT6FXNQsXBbONdq4Zcu8erNBiWH4g9t4WB8btM1r3uR45XXHXKV8q7H6TFMVw/wCxXlfA6R0kga6MBmThdwBIBvytrbmu/sHiMeM4e1tSxszo/upg8B4Jb7LiDzLSDfrdd/B9naKiLjT00cRfbMWizjblfjbwWRvHD7XBz5NR4a5XB10RFUUhERAfm6rjebtk+mtSU0mWUi8rxqWA8A08nHjfiBbqpBt1jNVRwXpoHSPkOQOa0vyaXzFoBv0HK/HoqoptkMVnvOaV7zfM7tSGl5vc3a4guur6or6pdHT+H6etv1bWsLpN9s6G7zY99dKKmdp7BjswzcZXA3trxaDxPPh1tdzAqkwzeVUUrxBWUjWhlmkMBhe0DhaM6EeAsrPwzEoauNs0Lw9j+BHzBHIjmCvLtzeX0Q+IK5z3TXHjHKM4tWtpoJZ3cImOcf0gleZ5ZJJ3lxu6SZ5PUlz3f3KubfFiXY0bYQdal4afys7zvnlHqq53eUbJa6N0hAZTh0zydGjsxoSToBmLVbQtsHI1aCPp0StLu2YwltDSxU4/02jMerjq8+riV1VVe1G9SxMdCwEC4MzwS39DOY8T8FrbGbzJGvMeISZmvIyyhoaGdQ4NHs+PLy4UuqbW4wy0d7i7Gv8AOPJbyr3fBj7qanbTRkh9VmDiDYhjbZ/U3A8rqewyte0Oa4ODgCCDmab8CCOIVTb9JG9pSj+INlJ8iWW+YKVJOaTK9LFStSaOPuw2PbXymedt4ICBlPB7+OU+60WJ63A6q9GNAFgLAcBwC4Ow+GCkoYIgNeza53XM8ZnX9Tb0UgXls90meam1zm/bwFTe+jZtkTmV8bQO1dkmA0BdYlj/ADNiD6K5FGN5FD2+HVDbXLWdoPOMh/0BXlUnGSI0TcZplb7kcTMdXJTk92ojzAe9Gb/yud8Fd682bvqgx4lSuHOTJ+9pb/VekwrNQsTyW6uOJ59zKIioMoREQGLJZZRAQXengLKildUBoEtMMwNtS2/faTzFtR0I8SoVuoxp1PVimLvu6m+nIPAu0jzALT106Ky94NW2HD6gk+0wsHiX90fW/oqS2VJFbTW49tH/ADi61VLdW8nd0MXbo5xl0s4/GSV76aguqoY+TIi797yD8mhQnCaGepkFPACXTaWvZthqS/3Ra58lKt7x/wAw/wCln1cpDuVw1mSaqI7xd2Y8AAHOt5kj9qsUttSZdG1UaJSXt/1m/hG6qijaPtDnzv594xs/SG628yuVtfuyiZE6aiLw6MFxic7OHAC5yE6h1uRvdWqhWVWzznJxVrLt25yZTW6Xap0UooZXXimv2N/4Hcco912unI+a52+ScuxAtPCOKMD1zOPzKjbpOxqi6PTspyW292XT6Kd768HIfFWAaPHZSeBF3MJ8wXD0C0YSsT9zpyhGGoUutyf5LWw5wMUZHAsZb9oWyo1u6xIVWHwPvd0bezf5x93X0APqpMsklhs4tkXGTT9wtLGYs9PM38Ucg+LSFurRxuYR08zzoGRyE+jCUXZ5Hs85bENvX0Y/5o/kb/0XpteeN1NH22JQaaRB8h/Swgf+nBehwrtQ/mRr1r+dfYyiIqDGEREBhYKyq73ibaiAOpKZ15TpI8cIweIB/Gfl5qUIuTwi6iid81CC/gjm9XaQVUopYnXjpyS8jg5/C3k0XHmT0X63TbPOnn+2PH3dPcM6OeRy8Gg38yFHdlNnJcSm7Nt2sbYySWuGjoOrjrYeqvrC8Pjpo2wxNysjFgP6nqTxJ6rRZJQjsR2tbdDS0rTVvnHP7/kqbfNBlq4n/jhA/a939wu3uTqwYZ4ebJA/0e231YV195mzT6+nD4hmlpyXNHNwPttHjoCPEW5qqtlNoZMMqO1DMwILJWHuuIvrx4OBHPxC9j89W3yRqS1Oi9OP1Lx/s9ELjbV4y2gpZJ3HVrSGDmXO0aB6/IFcL/E/DMmbPJm/B2Zz+X4fmq72jx2qx6oZFFE7KD93EOPi+Q8L258APnTCp556MFGisc8zWEu2+Dm7FYQ6urYo7XAcJJT7rDmN/M2Hqr42jwZldTSUz9BINDxLSNWuHkQFzNhtlWYZDYkOmlsZH26cGt90fPUqUJbZmXHgjrNT6lqcel0UTsTtHJglTJTVIIjLssoGuRw0EjRzBFr24ix5K7aSsjnYJI3te1wuHNIc0+RCrze1sr2zPt8LbviFpQOLmDg7xLfp5Kr8JxqqozenqHx3NyAbsPm03afgrNitW5dmh0R1UfUi8Pz9z03dV5vhx9sFL9kafvKq1xzDAbuJ8yA0ddeigv8AiXi9rdvH+bsm5v7fJcWgo6vFqoMDnSyykZ3uu4NA4uceTQOA9AkKHF5kQr0Uq5brGsLksDcfhRAmrCPatEzyb3nn45R6FWwFzsCwqOigjp4/ZiaB4nmSfEm59V0VTOW55MV0983IyiIoFRhfgkDUrWxGvbTszuDz0DGOlcfANaCqx2jxLFcUd2MNLPFEf4S0xl3jI82AHu3t5qcIOX2NWm0rvl2kvLbwjd233gAXp6J1zqHzch1EfU+9wHLqIZs5snV4i7NG3LGT3pX3DfG3N58vUhTXZjdoG2krSHEcIm+z+t3PyGniVY0ULWANa0NDQAABYDwAHBWuxQWI/k6c9dTpIenpVl+ZM5uzuBw0ETYYhoNXOPtOJ4ud4/QaLroiobbeWcSc3JuUnyFGNodiKKvOeSMskPF8ZyOP5uTvUKTpZE2nwewsnB5i8MriHdHSg3dUzOHQZW/OxUywPZ+loG5aeIMv7R4vd+Zx1K6qKTnKXbLLdTbasTk2ZREUCg/LhcKC4/uwoqpxfEXUzzxyAGM+OQ8PQhTtF7GTj0ThbODzF4KqpdzzQby1rnN6MjDD8STb4KfbPbP0uHs7OniDL+0fae49XOOp+nRddFKVkpdsnZfZZ9TMoiKBSEREBiyWWUQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREB//2Q==" alt="360" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Forma correta" é muito relativo. Eu sugeria o código abaixo, usando `display`, `position relative` e `transform` para deixar tudo alinhado.

Na `div` onde tem as duas imagens, você pode colocar a primeira (do círculo) normalmente, sem `position absolute`, e a segunda com `position absolute` centralizada com `transform`, assim uma vai ficar sobre a outra:

```css
.banner {
  background:orange ;
}

.wrap_description {
  display: flex;
}

.flex_box_description {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.flex_box_text {
  color: #d9dadb;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);-moz-transform:translate(0,-50%);transform:translate(0,-50%);top:50%;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
 <div class="wrap_description">
  <div class="flex_box_description">
   <div class="flex_box_text">
    Você está procurando alguma coisa para fazer em Curitiba? Quer você viva na área, tenha se mudado há pouco tempo ou esteja só de passagem, temos várias dicas e eventos imperdíveis. Você pode procurar por local, popularidade, eventos selecionados, eventos gratuitos... a escolha é sua. Pronto?
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex_box_description">
   <img style="margin-left:1px;" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_lveQq-e41T0/TChewY5E2xI/AAAAAAAAALM/LXlQxG3KwjI/s400/circulo.gif" alt="360" />
   <img style="position:absolute; -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);transform:translate(-50%,-50%);top:50%;left:50%; max-width: 150px; width: 100%; height: 100%; max-height: 150px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="360" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui desta forma, vlw

Answer (score 1):

> preciso colocar essa imagem com número 360 dentro da imagem que é um
>   circulo, qual a forma mais correta de se fazer isso?

Bom, vendo o código que você disponibilizou vejo que a ideia é literalmente colocar o 360° no meio de um circulo. Então fiz uma pequena alteração em seu código que as vezes pode te atender de uma forma mais simples.

**1°)** Deletei a imagem que representava o circulo já que nos próximos passos não vamos mais precisar dele.

**2°)** A imagem referente ao 360° foram adicionadas três propriedades (`padding`,`border`,`border-radius`).

- [Padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp): Utilizado para criar espaço em volta do elemento. Aqui estou usando um `padding` de `60px` para criarmos um bom espaço.
- [Border](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp): Aqui está sendo usada para delimitar o espaço de `60px` criado pelo `padding`
- [Border-radius](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp): E é aqui que alcançamos o efeito desejado, essa propriedade tem a capacidade de *"dobrar"* as quinas e transformar a borda do elemento em um circulo, criando o mesmo efeito da imagem que foi excluída.

**3°)** Repare que o resultado final está cortando uma parte do **°**(grau) da imagem 360°, isso pode ser facilmente corrigido caso você salve essa imagem com dimensões um pouco maiores.

**4°)** Dessa forma a imagem 360º sempre estará centralizada dentro de um circulo independente de outros fatores. Podendo se adaptar a vários tamanhos e etc.

```css
.size-um{
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.size-dois{
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.size-tres{
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img class='size-um' src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="360" />

<img class='size-dois' src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="360" />

<h5 style='font-family: arial;'>
   Quando diminuímos o tamanho da imagem, o circulo em volta pode ficar desproporcional, parar corrigirmos isso basta alterarmos o padding.
</h5>

<img class='size-tres' src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="360" />
```